# Anki does not run in Linux Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: anki

I did download the Anki and set up it, but a type "anki", Anki not open and when I click on icon happen same. The message that was showed is below.

```
 File "runanki.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "aqt/__init__.py", line 405, in run
  File "aqt/__init__.py", line 451, in _run
  File "aqt/profiles.py", line 136, in setupMeta
  File "aqt/profiles.py", line 505, in _loadMeta
resetting corrupt _global
Qt info: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found. 
Qt fatal: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.

Comment: It clearly says you are missing files. Wayland is one of the soultions that is suggested. This is the link to understanding Wayland and how to activate it. https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-disable-wayland-on-ubuntu-20-04-desktop

Answer (score 0):

This command worked for me!

```
sudo apt-get install libxcb-xinerama0
```